# How to notify client from server in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a **windows app** and a **web service** in server side, and on other side(client) a **windows form application**. I want to notify client from server when something change on server. One way is that client check the server constantly. But server will too busy because number of clients are about **100,000**. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: did you explored wcf duplex communication channel ?

Comment: I did not experience this!!!

Comment: how your windows form application communicate to server ?

Comment: by wcf, but i did not experience 'duplex communication' in wcf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- One way is using a *Duplex Contract*

[How to: Create a Duplex Contract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-create-a-duplex-contract)

> The duplex contract is one of three message patterns available to
>   Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) services. The other two message
>   patterns are one-way and request-reply. A duplex contract consists of
>   two one-way contracts between the client and the server and does not
>   require that the method calls be correlated. Use this kind of contract
>   when your service must query the  client for more information or
>   explicitly raise events on the client

- You could also use *Signalr* i guess

[Introduction to SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr)

> ASP.NET SignalR is a library for ASP.NET developers that simplifies
>   the process of adding real-time web functionality to applications.
>   Real-time web functionality is the ability to have server code push
>   content to connected clients instantly as it becomes available, rather
>   than having the server wait for a client to request new data.

**Update** [Answer to comment]

*WFC* and *Duplex Contracts* is very secure an reliable way to achieve your results. *Signalr* is a very lightweight approach and is'nt as robust or secure.

Yes you are right there is some sort of socket connection that will be required at the base level, though you really need to study these 2 options to work out what is mostly like best for you. I personally have had a lot of success with *Signalr* and use it  often, its  easy to setup, and fairly fault  tolerant. Though if security and reliability  is  a concern  then  *Duplex  Contracts* are probably your best bet

Comment: I think that on background of each these items is that client open socket to server. which item is better to use, that server fewer busy?